# Yarn run command fail but npm run works

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npm-scripts, npm-run

When I try to run `yarn run` command in a project I'm getting below error in git-bash.

`/d: /d: Is a directory`

`?[2K?[1G?[31merror?[39m Command failed with exit code 126.`

However if I run it using `npm run` it works fine.
Repo to reproduce the error - https://github.com/shabith/yarn-run-bug

Environment - Windows 10, git-bash

Things that I have already tried:

1. Reinstall Node.js
2. Reinstall Yarn

[image]

Comment: I can confirm you this is working on OSx, so it probably has to do with being executed on a Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks @Dez, It must be related to my working environment then. But I'm not sure how to fix that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a fix to this issue.

All I had to do is delete my npm `shell-script` using `npm config delete script-shell` and it start working.

More info can be found on the bug that I have raised in github - https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6086#issuecomment-423361321